# Problem with $.css() in Firefox

Tags: jquery

I have this situation where i want to call a certain element depended on the click value. When the link contains an image i want to show the image, otherwise i want to load a html page. I've styled the bar to close the whole thing different when the html page is loaded as if the image is loaded. Say i have this css (which is the styling when a html page is loaded)

```
#shadow,#shadowRoute { position:fixed;left:0;top:0;width:100%;height:100%;z-index:500;background:black;opacity:0.8; }
#shadowContent,#shadowContentRoute { position:fixed;z-index:550;background:white;padding:25px; }
#closebar,#closebarRoute { text-align:right;background:#ebdfd3;width:740px;padding:5px;height:25px;text-transform:uppercase; }
#content,#contentRoute { margin-top:25px;width:750px;height:450px;overflow:auto; }
#imageSelectPrevious { position:absolute;left:0;top:45px;width:80px;z-index:600; }
#imageSelectNext { position:absolute;right:0;top:45px;width:80px;z-index:600; }
.imageNavLink { display:block;text-indent:-9999px; }
```

I use the following code to show a loading image. This works pretty fine, except the closebar is styled in the background color, defined in the stylesheet.

```
$("#shadow").add($("#shadowContent")).fadeIn(500);    
$("#shadowContent").animate({width:'250px',height:'250px'},500).css({top:'25px',left:'50%',margin:'0 0 0 -125px',padding:'10px !important'}).empty().append('&lt;div id="closebar">&lt;a href="#close" id="closeBox">'+closeText+'&lt;/a>&lt;/div>').append('&lt;div id="content">&lt;/div>');
$("#closebar").animate({width:'250px'},500).css({background:'white !important',padding:'5px 0 !important'});
$("#closebar a").css({color:'#323232','font-weight':'bold',background:'url(http://www.cherrytrees.nl/tmp/Core/Images/closeIcon.jpg) left center no-repeat',padding:'0 0 0 20px'});
$("#content").animate({width:'230px',height:'230px'},500).css({margin:'0',padding:'90px'}).html("&lt;div id='imageSelectPrevious'>&lt;a href='#' id='prevImageLink' class='imageNavLink' title='' rel='prev'>Previous&lt;/a>&lt;/div>&lt;div id='imageSelectNext'>&lt;a href='#' id='nextImageLink' class='imageNavLink' title='' rel='next'>Next&lt;/a>&lt;/div>&lt;img id='popImageContainer' src='http://www.cherrytrees.nl/tmp/Core/Images/load.gif' style='margin:0'>&lt;/div>");
$("#prevImageLink").add($("#nextImageLink")).hide();
```

Ok, i now have some code which checks the image, get dimensions and everything. When the image is fully loaded i run the following code to change the container dimensions and display the image

```
$("#shadowContent").animate({width:newWidth+'px',height:newHeight+'px'},500).css({top:'25px',left:'50%',margin:'0 0 0 -'+(newWidth / 2)+'px !important'});
$("#content").animate({width:newWidth+'px',height:newHeight+'px'},500).css({margin:'0',padding:'0 !important'});
$("#closebar").animate({width:newWidth+'px'},500);
$("#popImageContainer").css({padding:'0 !important'});
```

Now this works fine in Chrome and Safari (IE not tested), but Firefox styles the closebar with the `#ebdfd3` background, somehow adds a padding to the image, and messes up the position of the container element.

And yes, the stylesheet is included *above* the javascript in my document

I really don't have a clue what to do, considering the fact it works in Chrome and Safari.. Does maybe anybody heard about a issue like this?

**Problem solved!**
The `!important` caused the problem! It now works fine!! Thanks!

Comment: This is awfully difficult to get into with the code alone, especially as you're not giving detailed info on what goes wrong. You'll probably need to show a live link

Comment: Also, what strikes me as problematic is the `0 !important` is the important really necessary?

Comment: Yeah, I don't think you can include `!important` flags in script like that... at least I've never had it work for me.

Comment: You're going to have to use Firebug to interactively tinker with the CSS and experimentally determine what's going on.

Comment: Oh! It actually was the !important stuff that caused the error! It works fine now!! Thanks!!

Comment: @Maurice, please post an answer to that effect, so that it might be useful to someone in future.

Comment: @Pekka, you should post an answer so Maurice can give you credit :P

Comment: I think it would be a good idea to indent your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `!important`: It won't work in this context.